# Modify products description by script

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

i need to modify all products description by sku : i have csv file with two column first column define sku and twice define description so how i can do that
this my script

```
      <?php
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

$csv                = new Varien_File_Csv();
$data               = $csv->getData('comment.csv'); //csv
array_shift($data);
  $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    try{
        $product
        ->setDescription($data[1])
        ->setShortDescription($data[1]) 
        ->addFieldToFilter('sku',$data[0]);
        $product->save();
        echo "done";
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
   echo Mage::log($e->getMessage()) . " Error"."</br>";
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: could you please share your CSV array i.e print_r($data) ?

Comment: did you try my solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code for update attribute:

```
<?php
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$csv->setDelimiter(',');//this is important to separate SKU with description

$data = $csv->getData('comment.csv'); //csv
for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++)
    {
try{
    $sku = $data[$i][0];
    $product_id = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku($sku);
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

    if ($product_id) {

        $description = 'description';
        $shortDescription = 'short_description';
        $updater = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action');
        $updater->updateAttributes(array($product_id), array($description => $data[$i][1],$shortDescription => $data[$i][1]), $storeId);
        echo 'Updated Product with SKU of ' . $sku;
        echo '<br>';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Product not found with SKU of ' . $sku;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo Mage::log($e->getMessage()) . " Error"."</br>";
}
}
```

**Note:** Advantage of above method is no need to product collection and no more load product!.
Before running script, please print your **$data** array and it should look like:

```
Array
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ab<!--sku-->
            [1] => test
        )

    [1] => Array
       (
            [0] => ba<!--sku-->
            [1] => again test
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through the data array not through product collection, Please try this code, it should be work

```
<?php
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

$csv                = new Varien_File_Csv();
$data               = $csv->getData('comment.csv'); //csv
array_shift($data);
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $sku = $item[0];
    $description = $item[1];
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
    $_product->setDescription($description);
    $_product->setShortDescription($description);
    $_product->save();
}
?>
```